Spyder doesn't highlight syntax in py3 file
Having a brand new installation of spyder 6.0.2 (under python 3.11.10, linux 5.15.0-122-generic) I cannot highlight syntax in py3 files (py files are highlighted). Is there a solution for that?

Is there a specific reason the scripts (must) have a ‘non-standard’ Python file extension?

Per the Python Module tutorial: “A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.”
